# call a string to a class then call that class?

Tags: c#

I need to call a private string from one class & put it within a second class. In my main method call on the second class I then need to print the strings for the first and second class... I know the second class call on the first class, I just don't know the code line to do that, then take that to the main class.

```
class nameFirst
{
    private string name_1= "zach";

    public string name_1 {
        get { return name_1; }
    }
}

class lastName
{
    nameFirst name1 = new nameFirst();
    private string lastName_1 = "clare";

    public string lastName_1 {
        get { return lastName_1; }
    }
}

class fullName
{
    public static void main(string [] args)
    {
        lastName last1 = new lastName();
        Console.WriteLine("Full name is {0} {1}", )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you make `name1` inside your class `lastName` private? Or why do you keep a reference to the first name in your last name class? This doesn't make much sense...

Comment: What are you trying to do, the code doesn't seem to make much sense

Comment: Can you try to explain what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

```
class lastName
{
    nameFirst name1 = new nameFirst();
    private string lastName_1 = "clare";

    public string firstName_2 {
        get { return name1.name_1; }
    }
    public string lastName_1 {
        get { return lastName_1; }
    }
}
```

You can expose the name_1 property from the nameFirst class in the lastName class.

```
class fullName
{
    public static void main(string [] args)
    {
        lastName last1 = new lastName();
        Console.WriteLine("Full name is {0} {1}", last1.firstName_2, last1.lastName_1);
    }
}
```

It's certainly ugly, but it gets the job done.

Comment: haha it is, right now I'm just working on the logic, not the beauty :) haha thank you, also if i had 5 classes, i would do the same thing just more of a chain reaction, such as 1 into 2, and 2 (containing 1) into 3, and so upon till i hit my fifth class ?

Comment: @user2447032 - Yup, that's the general idea.